# Disable Java Auto Update Prompt for 1.7u25 on Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, java, bug

I'm having a heck of a time trying to disable the option 
"Check for updates Automatically"

I ran composer to see what plist was being modified and it looks like
**~/Library/Preferences/com.oracle.javadeployment.plist**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"    "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>/com/oracle/javadeployment/</key>
    <dict>
        <key>deployment.macosx.check.update</key>
        <string>false</string>
</dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

So I experimented with changing that value to true or false and it would not effect the checkbox under the Java Control Panel > Update > Check for Updates Automatically

Your assistance would be much appreciated.

Initially I was looking @ /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin

Comment: What is the underlying problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Do you mean to say that you can not disable it in Java Control Panel ? or are you trying to have some kind of script do that?

Comment: I am trying to disable Java from prompting my users to update.

I found a script posted here, which turns off the auto update feature:
https://jamfnation.jamfsoftware.com/discussion.html?id=6489

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I'm trying to deploy these settings to a group of users... looks like running the script above is the best method.

Comment: @PaulMung if this ends up working for you please help make SO stronger by posting your own solution as an answer.

Comment: Why do you want to expose your users to known bugs and exploits? One main reason that Java is updated for applets is to stop known and used exploits

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open a Terminal and execute:

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.oracle.java.Java-Updater JavaAutoUpdateEnabled -bool false
```

Source: https://jamfnation.jamfsoftware.com/discussion.html?id=6489

**Update:**  This answer has been confirmed to work on OS X 10.11.5 (El Capitan)

Comment: Next time put the answer like you would expect from others, don't just link the article where you have sift through another huge thread.  The solution is do a "sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.oracle.java.Java-Updater JavaAutoUpdateEnabled -bool false" in Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a more general approach would be to unload  com.oracle.java.Java-Updater.plist via "**sudo launchctl unload com.oracle.java.Java-Updater.plist**" , and remove the plist from /Library/LaunchAgents?

Comment: Is this answer (which you know to solve the problem), a guess or a follow-up question?